# Data attribute returns undefined on selectbox

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute, rel

I'm trying to run a function once the user has clicked above some option of my select box. How ever, I'm trying to achieve this using data attributes and jQuery, but it does not work.

This is the code:

```
<select class="form-control" id = "add-languages" style = "margin-top:5px;">
                                    <option value = "">(Select your additional language)</option>
                                    <option value = "en" data-langfullname = "english">English (by default)</option>
                                    <option value = "es" data-langfullname = "spanish">Spanish</option>
                                    <option value = "gr" data-langfullname = "german">German</option>
                                    <option value = "ch" data-langfullname = "chinese">Chinese</option>
                                    <option value = "ru" data-langfullname = "russian">Russian</option>
                                    <option value = "jp" data-langfullname = "japanese">Japanese</option>
                                    <option value = "fr" data-langfullname = "french">French</option>
                                    <option value = "pt" data-langfullname = "portuguese">Portuguese</option>


$(function(){
        $("#add-languages").change(function(){
            alert($(this).data("langfullname"));

        });
    });
```

Here is my Fiddle... thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/BTtN8/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `this`, you are trying to access a data attribute of `<select>`. Instead, you'll need to access the data attribute of the selected `<option>`.

```
$('option:selected',this).data("langfullname");
```

Try it below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#add-languages").change(function() {
    alert($('option:selected', this).data("langfullname"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="add-languages" style="margin-top:5px;">
  <option value="">(Select your additional language)</option>
  <option value="en" data-langfullname="english">English (by default)</option>
  <option value="es" data-langfullname="spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="gr" data-langfullname="german">German</option>
  <option value="ch" data-langfullname="chinese">Chinese</option>
  <option value="ru" data-langfullname="russian">Russian</option>
  <option value="jp" data-langfullname="japanese">Japanese</option>
  <option value="fr" data-langfullname="french">French</option>
  <option value="pt" data-langfullname="portuguese">Portuguese</option>
  <option value="it" data-langfullname="italian">Italian</option>
  <option value="po" data-langfullname="polish">Polish</option>
  <option value="tu" data-langfullname="turkish">Turkish</option>
  <option value="du" data-langfullname="dutch">Dutch</option>
  <option value="ar" data-langfullname="arabic">Arabic</option>
  <option value="ko" data-langfullname="korean">Korean</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Absolutely true. Thanks!